# Invalid escape sequence in Literal from API call

Tags: swift

When I'm creating a String from this:

> "Spits fire that\nis hot enough to\nmelt boulders.\fKnown to cause\nforest fires\nunintentionally".

I am getting an error invalid escape sequence.

Now Xcode is highlighting `/f` in the string. When I remove `/f`, it works. The only thing is that this is the string I get back from an API call. So I'm pretty sure it will crash my app. So how would I get around this?

Comment: Have you tried to see if it crashes your app? What you're seeing is a compilation error, not an app crash.

Comment: Just finished trying it, and no it doesn't crash the app. I thought it would since it didn't allow me to create a string from it. Instead of /f it replaces it with \u{0C} whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

You keep writing `/f` in your question, but the characters in the string are `\f`. This is not a valid Swift escape sequence, so it's an error include in a Swift literal that supports escapes.

It is a valid escape sequence in C and in JSON, and decodes to the form-feed character (`\u{0c}`). It's very unlikely you actually want that character. But, if you using a JSON decoder, it should decode correctly, even though you could not write it that way as a Swift literal. This is identical to the fact that you can encode a character in JSON as `\u0020`, but that would not be valid Swift. In Swift, it would be written `\u{20}`. Swift and JSON do not have the same syntax. (And in URL-escaping, this would be `%20`; there are many syntaxes.)